# Find the area of the region in the xy-plane given by $0\le y \le 2x,\; 4\le 15x^2-y^2 \le 7$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the region in the xy-plane given by $0\le y \le 2x,\; 4\le 15x^2-y^2 \le 7$

how to solve using by substitution $u=16x^2-y^2,v=x^{-1}y$

any one can hemp please

Comment: You have

$$4\le 15x^2-y^2\implies y^2\le15x^2-4\implies |y|\le\sqrt{15x^2-4}$$

and

$$15x^2-y^2\le 7\implies y^2\ge15x^2-7\implies |y|\ge\sqrt{15x^2-7}$$

and also finally $\;0\le y\le 2x\;$ .

Can you sketch the above regions in a plane?

Comment: are the details of this question correct? Do you mean $15x^2$ or $16x^2$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn..yes ur correct i just mistake